# Could not load assembly 'Ticaret.Model'. Ensure it is referenced by the startup project 'Ticaret.Core'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC project that I created with blank solution, I get the following error: Could not load assembly 'Ticaret.Model'. Ensure it is referenced by the startup project 'Ticaret.Core'.

I tried to reference but it failed I want help to solve this problem.